# OpenJ9 VM Object Layout

Tags: java, jol, openj9

OpendJDK has a [Java Object Layout (JOL)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/) tool which allows to estimate instance real memory size of specified object.
It can show an object layout for HotSpot but will it be the same in OpenJ9?

Comment: No, unfortunatelly I need more detailed answer. Maybe wheb I have a time I'll try to analyze source code myself and write an answer to this question

Answer (score 1):

Well, IMHO, the answer is no, for *at least* the fact that if you count references sizes too, there is `UseCompressedOops` that *is* HotSpot specific. May be J9 has it too, but may be not.

There is the issue of padding too, in HotSpot objects are `8 bytes` aligned (there are more complicated things about inheritance), but I don't know if `J9` does that...

Comment: Yes, J9 has compressed references, and it also aligns objects to 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a system core (e.g. via -Xdump:system:events=vmstop) you can look at the sizes of live objects, including the padding and alignment using jdmpview's `!objectsizeinfo` command, e.g.:

```
> !objectsizeinfo java/lang/String

Object field size summary
=========================
Class             Total size  Data size  Space used  Instances  char  byte  short  int  long  float  double  boolean  object  hidden  
----------------  ----------  ---------  ----------  ---------  ----  ----  -----  ---  ----  -----  ------  -------  ------  ------  
java/lang/String  16          10*        66752       4172       0     2     0      0    0     0      0       0        1       0       
Class             Total size  Data size  Space used  Instances  char  byte  short  int  long  float  double  boolean  object  hidden  
Heap summary      66752       41720      66752       4172       0     8344  0      0    0     0      0       0        4172    0
```

Comment: a must read here would be Aleksey Shipilev - what head dumps are lying about